# How does google maps print work?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, printing

Even without a "printer-friendly" view to print directions, when I choose "File->Print" in my browser, the page is formatted differently than the original view. How does Google achieve this? Is it a special javascript facade?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There'll be a print stylesheet defined in the code, something along the lines of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

if the stylesheet were contained in a separate file. Or:

```
@media print {
    body { font-size: 10pt }
}
@media screen {
    body { font-size: 13px }
}
@media screen, print {
    body { line-height: 1.2 }
}
```

if the styles are defined in the body of the code. The last definition shows that the same style can be applied to multiple media types.

*I've no idea how Google organise their codebase, and it is irrelevant for the purposes of this answer.*

Recognised media types are:

> **all** Suitable for all devices.
>   **braille**
>   Intended for braille tactile feedback
>   devices.
>   **embossed** Intended for paged
>   braille printers.
>   **handheld** Intended
>   for handheld devices (typically small
>   screen, limited bandwidth).
>   **print**
>   Intended for paged material and for
>   documents viewed on screen in print
>   preview mode. Please consult the
>   section on paged media for information
>   about formatting issues that are
>   specific to paged media.
>   **projection**
>   Intended for projected presentations,
>   for example projectors. Please consult
>   the section on paged media for
>   information about formatting issues
>   that are specific to paged media.
>   **screen** Intended primarily for color
>   computer screens.
>   **speech** Intended for
>   speech synthesizers. Note: CSS2 had a
>   similar media type called 'aural' for
>   this purpose. See the appendix on
>   aural style sheets for details.
>   **tty**
>   Intended for media using a fixed-pitch
>   character grid (such as teletypes,
>   terminals, or portable devices with
>   limited display capabilities). Authors
>   should not use pixel units with the
>   "tty" media type.
>   **tv** Intended for
>   television-type devices (low
>   resolution, color,
>   limited-scrollability screens, sound
>   available).

[From here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: Actually this isn't the case on the page. They used @media print {} in their main style block, not an external stylesheet.

Comment: @bigmattyh - the code was intended as an example, not a definitive statement on how Google actually coded their pages.

Comment: @ChrisF - Funny that I was the only one of the three of us answerers who actually looked up how Google did it, before posting.  Great that you guys have edited your answers to reflect. :)

Comment: @bigmattyh - I did consider looking at the Google maps page - I even typed in the URL, but I figured they would have tuned their code so you wouldn't see the relevant sections ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks all of you for the great, detailed answers. I learned way more than I expected, and this will all be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

View Source -> Search for "@media print".

The google maps page defines a separate layout for print styles in the <style> declaration at the top of the page.  Their engineers have done a *really* fine job of obfuscating as much of the content as possible.

Comment: I don't think the obfuscation is intended for that purpose - I think it's all bandwidth reduction.

Comment: Yes and no... They make their code very hard to reverse-engineer, across all their apps.  It goes beyond mere compression.

Comment: Haha, whoever downvoted this is ridiculous. The answer is correct and verifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Google is doing this by specifying `@media print` for their styles on the page.

You can also do this is by specifying the "media" type for the `<link>` tag. You can specify that stylesheets should only be applied for screen display, or in this case for print.

Example from the [W3C CSS 2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html):

```
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="print, handheld" HREF="foo.css">
```

OR

```
@media print {
    body { font-size: 10pt }
}
```

Allowed types:

```
all, braille, embossed, handheld, print, projection, screen, speech, tty, tv
```